# Pull serverOutputValue as NSInteger

Tags: objective-c, nsinteger

Ho Everybody I aam trying to call php script thorugh my iphone application that return me a integer value as serverOutput

```
NSData *dataURL =  [NSData dataWithContentsOfURL: [ NSURL URLWithString: hostStr ]];    
    NSString *serverOutput = [[NSString alloc] initWithData:dataURL encoding: NSASCIIStringEncoding];

    NSInteger * userid  = [serverOutput integerValue];

    NSLog(@" %d" , userid);
```

But if my print my serverOutput string it is **2381164503** but my NSLog(@" %d" , userid) prints me **2147483647**. I dont know for some reason  it is parsing different value :(

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, NSInteger is a primitive type so you shouldn't declare userid as a pointer (by putting the asterisk in front).  Second, the value 2381164503 is too big for an NSInteger (max is 2147483647).

Try using a `long long` instead:

```
long long userid = [serverOutput longLongValue];
NSLog(@" %lld" , userid);  //use %lld instead of %d
```